# function won`t run in if statement (eventlistener && eventlistener) javascript

Tags: image, function, if-statement, events

I'm trying to get an if statement going to get api results.
First I put eventlisteners(click) on my images and when they are BOTH clicked, the get-api-results function should run.
I know I asked something similar before but I got that one screwed up, with this I`m a little closer I think.

Here`s the code

```js
import axios from 'axios';
const container = document.getElementById('container')

let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/301";

let img2 = document.createElement("img2");
img2.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";

const imgCheck = img.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log("check")
})
const img2Check = img2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log("ok")
})
img.onclick = function () {location.href  = "http://localhost:1234/pageTwo.html";};

document.body.appendChild(img);
document.body.appendChild(img2);



 if (imgCheck && img2Check){
     async function fetchRecipeOne() {
         try {
             const result = await axios.get('https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?query=pasta&maxFat=25&number=2&apiKey=0b4d29adff5f4b41908e8ef51329fc48', {
                 headers: {
                     "Content-Type": "application/json"
                 }
             })
             console.log(result);

         } catch (e) {
             console.error(e);
         }}
     fetchRecipeOne();
     
 } else {
     console.log('no results');
 }
```

And the html pages

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <img ><img/>

    
<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And page 2:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<img id="img2"><img/>

<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, I`m pretty new to this stuff so if can give me enough details to sort this out you would do me a big favour.
Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener()` does not return anything.

Maybe you can create a variable and change it in the `eventlistener`, like so:

```
let imgCheck = false;
img.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  imgCheck = true;
});

let img2Check = false;
img2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  img2Check = true;
});
```

Also you redirect the user when he click on `img`, reset the click so to say. Maybe delete that

And the where you define `img2` you try to create an element with the name 'img2' which isn't a valid element.
So change:

```
let img2 = document.createElement("img2");
```

To:

```
let img2 = document.createElement("img");
```

Lastly you check is the user has clicked on both the images when the script runs, what you can do is set the if statement in the `async` function, and call the function when the user clicks on a `img`.

So it could look something like:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
const container = document.getElementById('container')

let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/301";

let img2 = document.createElement("img");
img2.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";

let imgCheck = false;
img.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  imgCheck = true;
  fetchRecipeOne();
});
let img2Check = false;
img2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  img2Check = true;
  fetchRecipeOne();
});

document.body.appendChild(img);
document.body.appendChild(img2);

async function fetchRecipeOne() {
  if (imgCheck && img2Check) {
    try {
      const result = await axios.get('https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?    query=pasta&maxFat=25&number=2&apiKey=0b4d29adff5f4b41908e8ef51329fc48', {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
      })
      console.log(result);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('no results');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm very sorry for my late reply, I didn't register the notification that you answered- thank you very much for your help!
I`ll ty it out and let you know if it worked.